# excel 2003 vba macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro in excel 2003 which does the following:
From multiple cells in a given range (ex a11:z20), highlight the cells
based on its changing cell value (ex 60 to 100), 9-10 different condition. values that are false are not highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean some functions like this one?

```
Sub FillCells()
Dim myCells As Range
For Each myCells In Range("A11:Z20").Cells
    If myCells.Value >= 60 And myCells.Value <= 100 Then
        myCells.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next myCells
End Sub
```

Comment: @vtraeye if this answer solved your question then you should consider marking it as "accepted" (by using the check mark next to the answer).